# PHP cURL results in 403 Forbidden

Tags: php, curl, http-status-code-403

I am trying to cURL a remote site that results in a 403 Forbidden error. From the same server I can run the following two commands via Terminal. The first fails while the second works. How can I get my PHP code to match up to the second terminal command?

This Terminal command results in nothing returned.

```
curl http://www.barneys.com
```

This Terminal command results in a proper result (the HTML of the page)

```
curl -L http://www.barneys.com
```

My PHP Code:

```
$ch = curl_init('http://www.barneys.com');
$http_headers = array(
'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:40.0)' . 'Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0',
'Accept: */*',
'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest',
'Referer: http://www.barneys.com', # IMPORTANT
'Accept-Language: pt-BR,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3',
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $http_headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://www.barneys.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$redirectURL = curl_getinfo($ch,CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
curl_close($ch);

echo $response;
```

**EDIT:** Here is the log from the cURL request via PHP:

```
* About to connect() to www.barneys.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 23.204.27.110... * connected
* Connected to www.barneys.com (23.204.27.110) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: www.barneys.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:40.0)Gecko/20100101 Firefox/40.0
Accept: */*
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
Referer: http://www.barneys.com
Accept-Language: pt-BR,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Connection: keep-alive

< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< Server: AkamaiGHost
< Mime-Version: 1.0
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 265
< Expires: Mon, 11 Apr 2016 23:22:16 GMT
< Date: Mon, 11 Apr 2016 23:22:16 GMT
< Connection: close
< 
* Closing connection #0
```

Comment: First the status code is 301 . Basically in curl -L states to follow the redirect, so `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);` should be enough. Attach some output or error to debug the error

Comment: Thanks @georoot I have added the log above. Let me know if that helps!

Comment: Seems like if you add a header, `'Connection: keep-alive'` it will work.

Comment: @drew010 Unfortunately that didn't fix it.

Answer (score 2):

There is no request header included in your php cURL request. To fix that, add the following line right before your setting the `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER` option:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
```

From the [PHP curl docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php):

> CURLOPT_HEADER    TRUE to include the header in the output.

Also, if you add a trailing slash to the url, the URL won't need to be rebuilt by cURL. A lot of your code appears to be unnecessary. Here is a trimmed down working example:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init('http://www.barneys.com/');
$http_headers = array(
    'User-Agent: Junk', // Any User-Agent will do here
);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $http_headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $response;
```